# Identifying Jquery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to javascript and jquery.

What does this selector mean: " #LayoutColumn2 > div > div > div > ul"

Contect (the function it comes from):

```
function loadNextTier(tierID, changedItemValue) {
    linkArray.length = 0;
$("#placeholderForLoad").load(changedItemValue + " #LayoutColumn2 > div > div > div > ul", function(){
    $("#placeholderForLoad li").each(function(){
        var itemName = $(this).children("a").text();
        var itemValue = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
        linkArray.push(itemValue+";"+itemName);
    });
    if (tierID == "tier1") {
        tierID = "tier2";
    }
    else if (tierID == "tier2"){
        tierID = "tier3";
    }
    else if (tierID == "tier3") {
        tierID = "tier4";
    }
    resetTiers(tierID);
    fillMyList(linkArray, tierID);
});
```

Comment: It tells jQuery to select any `ul` that is a direct child of a `div`that is a direct child of a `div`that is a direct child of a `div` that is a direct child of the element named `LayoutColumn2`

Comment: @Jack Actually, it's not about jQuery, it's about selectors ([descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) in particular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will match the following structure

```
<any_tag id="LayoutColumn2">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul> <-- matches this tag
          <li>
            <ul> <-- doesn't match. you only fetched children, not descendants
```

`#LayoutColumn2 > div > div > div > ul` means:

> get the `<ul>` that is a child of a `<div>`, which is a child of a `<div>`, which is a child of a `<div>`, which is a child of a tag with an id of `LayoutColumn`.

By the way, the term *descendant* means any element that comes nested (no matter how deep) in a certain element. CSS selectors, without combinators, normally target descendants.

The term *child* or *children* means elements that are *direct descendants* or are descendants only 1 level deep from the element. That's the purpose of `>`.

Comment: Joseph, thank you for your answer. You answered exactly what I asked, but I should have asked differently

Answer (score 1):

Read it from right to left:

`ul` inside `div` inside `div` inside `div` inside element with `id 'LayoutColumn2'`